# how to create query which set value in one column the same as value of column in another table

Tags: sql-server

I mean I've got one table

```
table1
idbook idauthor  title     magazine
 1       NULL   title_1   magazine_1
 2        2     title_2   magazine_2
```

and another

```
table2
idauthor   name     surname
   1      name_1   surname_1
   2      name_2   surname_2
```

And I want to write a query which update table1 and set value 'idauthor' for title_1 the same as the 'idauthor' in table2 with name_1.

How it will be look like?Or it is not possible?

How

Comment: How can u join the two tables if they dont have a common col..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the common column is idauthor, it could be thought of as a foreign key. But since there is no way to match table1's row with table2, you would have to do kind of a dirty update statement, that will ONLY work for the example given above, and not for other scenarios.

```
UPDATE table1 SET idauthor = (SELECT idauthor FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE "name_1" AND surname LIKE "surname_1") WHERE idauthor ISNULL;
```

This query would update ALL of table1's rows that have a NULL value in the idauthor column, and set it to the one you're searching with name_1 and surname_1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a matching column between `table1` and `table2`, I'm going to guess there's something missing from this example.  But I'll write this out assuming `table2` has a column `idbook` that matches with `table1`.

```
update table1, table2
set table1.idauthor = table2.idauthor
where table1.idbook = table2.idbook
```

If you don't have a matching column (or columns), then no you can't do the update.

Comment: Sth like this? `update table1,table2 set table1.idauthor = table2.idauthor where table2.name = 'name_1'`.